# Cannot remove file from data lake store using runbook

Tags: powershell, azure-data-lake, azure-runbook

I am trying to run a runbook on azure that contains the following command:

Remove-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem

When the Runbook is run, the following error comes out:

"Remove-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem : The term 'Remove-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,..."

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This issue typically happens when there is a version mismatch between PS modules in your runbook and the Azure Automation account. To resolve, you will need to update your Azure PS Modules within the Azure Automation Account. "update" steps are published [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-azure-modules#updating-azure-modules).

Important note:

"Because modules are updated regularly by the product group, changes can occur with the included cmdlets, which may negatively impact your runbooks depending on the type of change, such as renaming a parameter or deprecating a cmdlet entirely. To avoid impacting your runbooks and the processes they automate, it is recommended that you test and validate before proceeding. If you do not have a dedicated Automation account intended for this purpose, consider creating one so that you can test many different scenarios and permutations during the development of your runbooks, in addition to iterative changes such as updating the PowerShell modules. After the results are validated and you have applied any changes required, proceed with coordinating the migration of any runbooks that required modification and perform the following update as described in production."